# Google Authentication Requirement For Accessing Reporting API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

We are trying to use the Google Reporting API from a .NET Core application but are completely confused as to the kind of Authentication requirement.
There seems to be several ways from Keys to Other methods.

Does anyone know what kind of Credentials and how it should be used when trying to access Analytics data using the Reporting API from .NET Core MVC Application

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Man thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your credentials for your application here: https://console.developers.google.com/apis. This will give you a client ID and client secret (Note - please make sure https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground as an authorized redirect uri). Then go to https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground to create authorization tokens. The access token you are given should be sent to the Google API through the header and value: "Authorization" : "Bearer {{AccessToken}}". If your token expires, you can retrieve a new one by hitting the OAUTH api (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token), sending refresh_token, client_id, client_secret, grant_type and access_type in the query and 'user-agent': 'google-oauth-playground' in the header.

If you get stuck, implement the google API the way they describe here in their quick start guides: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/ . You can then use developer tools to see exactly what values are being sent where.

Hope this helps. :)